# PHPBB run code on install & uninstall module. How to create table during module installation and drop it on uninstall

Tags: php, module, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm trying to create my own ACP PhpBB module.

I followed some instructions and it works well.

But now I want to change it.

It has to create new table on installation and drop it on uninstall. I found two methods install & uninstall in acp_foo_info.php in acp/info folder.

I wrote my code inside, but it doesn't work:

```
    function install()
    {
        global $db;
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phpbb_test` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `key` text NOT NULL,
              `val` text NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;";
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
        $db->sql_freeresult($result);
    }

    function uninstall()
    {
        global $db;
        $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `phpbb_test`;";
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
        $db->sql_freeresult($result);
}
```

What seems to be the problem and where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you doing any debugging? Would you get error messages if the queries failed, for example? Are the methods ever actually called?

Comment: NO, it seems that methods do not called. But it I found that it is the only way to do something on install/uninstall.